# Linq To XML - Can’t Remove Node

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

I have the following list

```
<Inventory>
  <Car ID="1000">
    <PetName>Jimbo</PetName>
    <Color>Red</Color>
    <Make>Ford</Make>
  </Car>
  <Car ID="1001">
    <PetName>Jimbo</PetName>
    <Color>Red</Color>
    <Make>Ford</Make>
  </Car>
</Inventory>
```

I am trying to remove the `Car` node with ID = 1000, but i can't get it right

Here is my Code, note that the debugger never hits `e.Remove`:

```
    Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("Test.xml")

    Dim e As XElement = From element
                        In doc.Elements("Inventory").Elements("Car")
                        Where element.Attribute("ID").Value = "1000"
                        Select element
    e.Remove()
```

Comment: you need to save document after modifying `doc.Save()` :)

Comment: Konrad Thanks i have but that was not the problem 

The LINQ query returns an IEnumerable<XElement>, not a single XElement and thanks To Ahmad i now know this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LINQ query returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>`, not a single `XElement`. Try this instead:

```
Dim e = From element
        In doc.Root.Elements("Car")
        Where element.Attribute("ID").Value = "1000"
        Select element

e.Remove()
```

If that doesn't work make sure you have `Option Infer` enabled to use implicitly typed variables or change the initialization to `Dim e As IEnumerable(Of XEelement) = ...` to be explicit.

Since you're using an `XDocument` you can use the `Root` property instead of looking for the `Inventory` node, i.e., `doc.Root...` instead of `doc.Elements("Inventory")...`.

Comment: You are still returning an `IEnumerable`. Use the `Single` extension method to get the first element from this collection.

Comment: Thanks Ahmad - Worked Like a charm. Kudos to you